# Update TaxDetails in Sales order when Override check box is clicked

Tags: events, acumatica

I am customizing Sales order screen to populate Customer Tax Zone ID when Override tax zone check box is checked.

When "Override Check box" is clicked, I want to populate tax zone from project screen into the Customer taxZone ID and parallelly tax details in Tax tab should also populate based on the customer tax zone but this is not happening, I can populate Customer tax zone in its but unable to populate tax details.  Below is the code I am using.

```
public class SOOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{
       
     protected void SOOrder_OverrideTaxZone_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = (SOOrder)e.Row;

        SOOrderEntry docgraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();

        PMProject proj = PXSelect<PMProject, Where<PMProject.contractID, Equal<Required<PMProject.contractID>>>>.Select(Base, row.ProjectID);
        ContractExt contract = PXCache<Contract>.GetExtension<ContractExt>(proj);

        row.TaxZoneID = contract.UsrCustomerTaxZone;
        
   }
    
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use `sender.SetValueExt<SOOrder.taxZoneID>(row, contract.UsrCustomerTaxZone);` to execute all needed events after the TaxZoneID changing. Your code will be the follwing:

```
protected void SOOrder_OverrideTaxZone_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    var row = (SOOrder)e.Row;

    SOOrderEntry docgraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();

    PMProject proj = PXSelect<PMProject, Where<PMProject.contractID, Equal<Required<PMProject.contractID>>>>.Select(Base, row.ProjectID);
    ContractExt contract = PXCache<Contract>.GetExtension<ContractExt>(proj);

    sender.SetValueExt<SOOrder.taxZoneID>(row, contract.UsrCustomerTaxZone);     
}
```